# laravel save,update data into two tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Am having problem updating  data into pivot tables.

```
users[id->autoincrement,username,password,firstname,lastname,lga,email]

    class User extends Eloquent
    {
      public function lga()
        {
            return $this->HasMany('LGA');
        }
    }
```

---

```
userslga[id->autoincrement,user_id,lga_id]



 public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('user');
        }

        public function lga()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('lga');
        }
```

---

```
lga[id->autoincrement,lg_name]

class LGA extends Eloquent
{
  public function lga()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

---

```
 When i tried querying relationship,like User::find($id)->lga  i could not figure that out.but i eventually made it work using this:





$U_LGA      = UserLga::where('user_id',$id)->lists('lga_id');
```

Now my problem is that i can store data into related tables from my controller like this:

```
if ($validation->passes()) 
                {

                    $user = new User;

                    $user->email            = Input::get('email');
                    $user->username         = Input::get('username');
                    $user->firstname        = Input::get('firstname');
                    $user->lastname         = Input::get('lastname');
                    $user->type             = Input::get('type');
                    $user->phone            = Input::get('phone');
                    $user->password         = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));


                    $user->save();

                //save each users lga
                foreach(Input::get('LGA') as $LGS)
                {
                    $userlga = new UserLga;

                    $userlga->user_id       = $user->id;
                    $userlga->lga_id        = $LGS;

                    $userlga->save();
                }
                //end

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','New user profile successfully created');
                }

                //return json error
                return Response::json($validation->messages());
```

But Updating would be a problem as UserLga::find($id) would not be valid because it the same as select from userlga where id = $id,where as am suppose to be updating all teh row where the user_id is the present user id am editing and add additional lga if more lga was checked.

I need help on how to do this am confused.Or am i getting the concept wrong or is Eloquent relationship query what am suppose to do,

please someone help?

EDIT

I WOULD LIKE TO RUN THE FOLLOWING QUERIES

```
UserLga::where('user_id',$uid)->lists('lga_id');
```

I WOULD LIKE TO DO BELOW IN ABETTER WAY TO

```
$statement2 = "SELECT * FROM facility where LGA_id = '$fulga' ";

        //loop through lga id to build query
        foreach($LGA_id as $fax)
        {
            $statement2.= " "."OR"." "."LGA_id=". "'".$fax."'";
        }

        //FACILITY for User assigned LGA
         $facility = DB::Select($statement2);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//generate all lgaid covered by user
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$ulga = UserLga::where('user_id',$uid)->lists('lga_id');

    //remove the first lgaid in array to build query and avoid repetition


$sulga = array_shift($ulga);



// query
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM lga where id = '$sulga' ";

        //loop through lga id to build query
        foreach($ulga as $lga)
        {
            $statement.= " "."OR"." "."id=". "'".$lga."'";
        }

        //user assigned lga
          $LGA = DB::Select($statement);
```

AM SORI THIS LOOKS ROUGH A BIT BUT I WANT TO ACHIVE BETTER USING ELOQUENT RELATION QUERY

Comment: Just show the query you'd like to run.

Comment: Please simplify your question and only ask one question at a time. I can't even tell what you are asking for.

Comment: i simply want to make eloquent relationship queries.so that i dont have messed up codes,like the one you see above.

Comment: tried a few things but did not work out